# How to programmatically ask if Mathematica is running as an administrator

Tags: programming, system-variables

To avoid execution problems in a program I need to know if Mathematica has been "Run as administrator".  What would be the cleanest way to programmatically getting this information?

Comment: Which OS?  Windows from the wording but can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I work on Windows.

Comment: See this if you want a command line method: [(4051883)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4051883/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Your response is clearly an answer to the question.  I use Mathematica as much as possible, so I would rather not have to go somewhere else for a solution.  In other words, maybe your code should be packed in a function (RunningAsAdministratorQ) and included as part of the Wolfram Language.

Comment: I don't think that Mathematica has this built in (one never knows as there is a lot of stuff which is not documented or hard to find). So I think you can either a) use a indirect method as Mr.Wizard has suggested (which might of course give a wrong answer, e.g. when someone has played with permissions of $InstallationDirectory), you can b) fire a command line tool (also suggested already) or use NETLink to access the corresponding Windows API call (which I don't know but certainly exists...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only method I am aware of is to attempt an operation that requires administrator-level permissions and look for a `General::privv` message:

```
Check[
  (CreateDirectory @ #; DeleteDirectory @ #) & @ 
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "test"}]; True,
  False,
  General::privv
] // Quiet
```

This should return `True` if it is run with administrator control and `False` if not.

Comment: This is a clean workaround.  I was hoping for a function call though.

Comment: @Ariel Quite likely there is a better way but at least this works in the mean time.

Comment: +1 This is a nice direct method.  Funny story: I once ran into a case where a very locked-down corporate virus scanner unceremoniously terminated my program when it tried to use [a similar technique](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.ca/2014/04/eclipse-osgi-windows-virus.html).

Comment: @ArielSepulveda Well, those *are* function calls you're looking at. If you want just a single function call, wrap a function around that code :)

Answer (score 9):

It may suit your purpose to use the Windows API function [IsUserAnAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It can be accessed through NETLink like this:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
isUserAnAdmin = DefineDLLFunction["IsUserAnAdmin", "shell32.dll", "bool", {}];

isUserAnAdmin[]
(* True if Mathematica was launched elevated, False otherwise *)
```

It is also possible to to use the shell command *whoami* to determine the Mandatory Label which, in turn, can tell us if the current session is running elevated:

```
isElevated[] :=
  !StringFreeQ[
    Import["!whoami /groups | find \"Mandatory Label\"", "Text"]
  , "S-1-16-12288"|"S-1-16-16384"
  ]

isElevated[]
(* True if Mathematica was launched elevated, False otherwise *)
```

The magic strings in `isElevated` are the security identifiers (SIDs) denoting the elevated [integrity levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx).  This text-based solution has the advantage that it does not require NETLink to be loaded.  On the other hand, it is more brittle should the output format of *whoami* ever be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can do it using [`IsUserAnAdmin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-isuseranadmin) SHELL32 function on Windows, without using NETLink:

```
isUserAnAdmin = ForeignFunctionLoad[
 Environment["SystemRoot"] <> 
  "/System32/shell32.dll", "IsUserAnAdmin", {} -> "CUnsignedChar"];

isUserAnAdmin[]
```

The Windows system ABI has a BOOL same size as a CHAR.