# Are there any functions to change file permissions?

Tags: files-and-directories

I looked but couldn't find any functions that would let me manipulate file permissions from Wolfram Language. I'm talking about things like read-only (on Windows), writable (on Unix), executable (ditto)...

On Unix I can call the `chmod` executable to do it, but it seems like a roundabout way of going about it. On Windows I'd do the same by executing `attrib`.

*I only need to do it under the regular user account, not with administrative/root privileges*.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Wolfram language wants to be platform independent, but it's hard to design a platform agnostic permission API. IE, Python's `os.chmod` silently fails on Windows where you instead have to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500472/419116) , ouch

Answer (score 0):

```
RunProcess[{"Attrib", "+R", "U:\Tmp\USBLog.csv"}, All]
(* Where "U:\Tmp\USBLog.csv" is any file name. *)
```

Works for me.

I found this doing a search on "Execute a command" in the Mathematica documentation.

Comment: Yes, that of course works, but given how slow process spawning is in Windows, this is two orders of magnitude slower than syscalls to do the same thing...

Answer (score -2):

[call as admin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84932/how-to-programmatically-ask-if-mathematica-is-running-as-an-administrator)

Mathematica, as a frontend with KI, is too insecure to allow  system  calls with administative rights.

Any of my attempts to test such scripts to change the standard security bits,  induced  a reinstallation of  the system (my experience: loosing the complete content of personal folders).

For tests one needs a machine that loads the system from a server or a security backup card.

Comment: I don't need admin rights, I just want to change file permissions as the user running wolfram language. Mathematica - as any other program - needs to issue millions of system calls to get anything done. It's not as if changing file permissions is any different from writing a new file. Sub-processes that Mathematica invokes, such as the C compiler, change file permissions plenty of times, and so on. I think you misunderstood my intent, but I will clarify that in the question.